# Combine multiple dictionaries into one pandas dataframe in long format

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have several dictionaries set up as follows:

```
Dict1 = {'Orange': ['1', '2', '3', '4']}
Dict2 = {'Red': ['3', '4', '5']}
```

And I'd like the output to be one combined dataframe:

```
| Type | Value |
|--------------|
|Orange|   1   |
|Orange|   2   |
|Orange|   3   |
|Orange|   4   |
| Red  |   3   |
| Red  |   4   |
| Red  |   5   |
```

I tried splitting everything out but I only get Dict2 in this dataframe.

```
mydicts = [Dict1, Dict2]
for x in mydicts:
    for k, v in x.items():
        df = pd.DataFrame(v)
        df['Type'] = k
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is using `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame, mydicts), axis=1).melt().dropna()

  variable value
0   Orange     1
1   Orange     2
2   Orange     3
3   Orange     4
4      Red     3
5      Red     4
6      Red     5
```

---

If performance matters, you can initialise a single DataFrame using `DataFrame.from_dict` and `melt`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({**Dict1, **Dict2}, orient='index').T.melt().dropna()
  variable value
0   Orange     1
1   Orange     2
2   Orange     3
3   Orange     4
4      Red     3
5      Red     4
6      Red     5
```

Or, using `stack` instead of `melt` (slightly slower, just for completeness):

```
res = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict({**Dict1, **Dict2}, orient='index').T
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=1)
         .sort_values('level_1'))
res.columns = ['Type', 'Value']

print(res)
     Type Value
0  Orange     1
1  Orange     2
2  Orange     3
3  Orange     4
0     Red     3
1     Red     4
2     Red     5
```

The dictionary unpacking syntax works with python3.6. On older versions, replace `{**d1, **d2}` with `{k: v for d in mydicts for k, v in d.items()}`.

Comment: Is there a way to iterate through the dictionaries in your second example instead of naming them individually?

Comment: @ATCH_torn Yes, see the footnote I just added please.

Answer (score 2):

#### Comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [(t, v)
     for t, V in {**Dict1, **Dict2}.items()
     for v in V],
    columns=['Type', 'Value']
)

     Type Value
0  Orange     1
1  Orange     2
2  Orange     3
3  Orange     4
4     Red     3
5     Red     4
6     Red     5
```

Answer (score 2):

After `stack` , it become a [unnest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218939/7964527) problem

```
s=pd.DataFrame(mydicts).stack().reset_index(level=1)
unnesting(s,[0])
Out[829]: 
   0 level_1
0  1  Orange
0  2  Orange
0  3  Orange
0  4  Orange
1  3     Red
1  4     Red
1  5     Red
```